# Binding LET variables to new values in CLisp

Tags: binding, lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to take the minimum and maximum values of a list and return them as a cons.

```
;;
;; Find minimum and maximum of a list
;;
(defun min-max (l)
  (let ((n 0) (min 0) (max 0) (size (numAtomsInList l)))
    (loop (when (= n (- size 1)) (return))
      (cond
        ((> (nth n l) (nth (+ n 1) l))) (setq min 5) ;(nth n l)) 
        ((< (nth n l) (nth (+ n 1) l))) (setq max 7) ;(nth n l))  
        (t (setq max n))
      )
      (incf n)
    )
    (cons min max)
  )
)
```

When running the function without the SETQs before the min & max variables it compiles fine, but I'm getting the result (0 . 0) - the original values that were set in the LET. With the SETQs, it's giving me the error:

Error: Attempt to take the value of the unbound variable `SETQ'.

How else would I change the value of min and max as I loop through the list? Why is it assuming that SETQ is a variable when syntactically it is correct?

Comment: Please consider investing a few minutes to learn about proper [Lisp code formatting](http://dept-info.labri.fr/~strandh/Teaching/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html).

Comment: If you're already using **loop**, why not use its variable update forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are grouping the forms in the `cond` body incorrectly. `cond` clauses should look like `(CONDITION BODY)`; you have

```
(cond
  ((> (nth n l) (nth (+ n 1) l)))
  (setq min 5)
  ;; etc
  )
```

Whereas you want

```
(cond
  ((> (nth n l) (nth (+ n 1) l))
   (setq min 5))
  ;; etc
  )
```

If you're coming from a Clojure background, you'll find that the grouping for many Common Lisp forms differ from their Clojure analogues.

To expand on the reason for the precise error you're seeing, if you have something like

```
(cond
  (setq x y))
```

`cond` will try and evaluate `setq` as a value, not as a functiony thing (recall that in Common Lisp, symbols can have both a function and a value binding); it's the same as writing `(when setq x y)`, and if we bind a value to `setq` we no longer get an unbound variable error.

```
? (let ((setq t) (x :x) (y :y)) (cond (setq x y)))
:Y
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the issue pointed out by Huw, your code has a serious efficiency problem: it uses `nth`, which needs to walk the whole list each time; in effect, you are writing an algorithm that is quadratic.  As a general rule of thumb, you should not use `nth` with a variable argument except if you really know what you are doing.

In order to be efficient, you should walk the input list sequentially and never start from the beginning.  If, like me, you're an old fart, you can do that using a `do` loop:

```
(defun min-max (l)
  (let ((min (car l)) (max (car l)))
    (do ((l (cdr l) (cdr l)))
        ((null l) (cons min max))
      (when (< (car l) min) (setq min (car l)))
      (when (> (car l) max) (setq max (car l))))))
```

If you prefer, you can use the fancy `loop` thingie:

```
(defun min-max (l)
  (let ((min (car l)) (max (car l)))
    (loop for e in (cdr l)
          do (when (< e min) (setq min e))
          do (when (> e max) (setq max e)))
    (cons min max)))
```

Or, Scheme-style, you can use tail recursion (and ignore the old Common Lisp programmers who tell you that it's not portable):

```
(defun min-max-3 (l)
  (let ((min (car l)) (max (car l)))
    (labels
        ((mm (l)
           (cond ((null l) (cons min max))
                 (t (when (< (car l) min) (setq min (car l)))
                    (when (> (car l) max) (setq max (car l)))
                    (mm (cdr l))))))
      (mm (cdr l)))))
```